# How do I theme the whisker menu in Xubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: xubuntu, themes, gtk, menu, whisker

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 with whisker menu and trying to change the theme of whisker menu. I have read several tutorials but without success. I have in my home directory a .gtkrc-2.0 file  with this content:

[image: .gtkrc-2.0 content]

Also I read that I need to add this configuration in */home/vladimir/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css*. I did but NO effect.
As well in */home/vladimir/.config/gtk-2.0/gtk.css*. NO effect. 
What I'm doing wrong? Is something is missing?

Thanks, Vladi

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have found a little more info on this issue but at least I hope to point you in the right direction, the confusion seems to be that whisker menu uses GTK 3 these days and so older methods are no longer viable.

Instead, try navigating to '~/.config/gtk-3.0/' and edit (or create) 'gtk.css' in this file you can make changes similar to the older methods, for example:

```
#whiskermenu-window {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #ccc;
}

/* Make sidebar buttons match */
#whiskermenu-window button {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #ccc;
}
#whiskermenu-window button:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #fff;
}
#whiskermenu-window button:checked {
    background-color: #606060;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Make treeview match */
#whiskermenu-window treeview {
    background-color: #404040;
    color: #ccc;
}
#whiskermenu-window treeview:hover {
    background-color: #808080;
    color: #fff;
}
```

and then re-login to see if that has any effect.
Source: https://gottcode.wordpress.com/2017/10/21/theming-whisker-menu-redux/